# Is there any point to RSpec'ing routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

In an app I'm currently working on, there are a bunch of routing specs for example:

> ```
> it "should match { :controller => 'update_reports', action => 'index' } to GET /update_reports" do
>   { get: "/update_reports" }.should route_to(:controller => "update_reports", :action => "index")
> end
> ```

Is it really worth the effort + runtime to have these type of tests?

I havent run into many instances where a route was deleted and other controller tests wouldnt catch it...

But I'm admittedly no-rspec expert.

Answer (score 1):

I don't test routes really often. I only do this for:

- the one I consider of major importance (like payment or payment callbacks)
- the one with complex logic and or constraints

---

Just another detail: I consider basic routes tested because I'm coding controller and integration specs.

Comment: Agreed. My mental question is: "Is this route non-standard in any way?" (for example, /thing/1/subitem/2 ?) If so, it gets a route spec

Comment: these are really standard nested resources

Comment: Right, but they're also not exactly everyday routes either, so you might want some extra care around them.